# Missing MSBuild\..\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, build-process

When I try to build the solution in VS, I get this error:

> error  : The project file could not be loaded. Root element is missing.  >C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets

Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets file is there when browsed using file manager. None of the projects are getting loaded.

I tried importing Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets to csproj files as well (mimicking `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"` />).  As most of the other info found on web, there's no .user file either.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Shot in the dark but did you try running in administrative mode?

Comment: I run as admin always.

Comment: Try installing hotfix for .NET Framework 4.5.1 [2925384](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2925384)

Comment: Didn't fix it. Even though it did not contain the problem child; _MS.Data.Entity.targets_ I tried with hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to uninstall .NET Framework and run Visual Studio Repair tool to get it back on board.